# Site-to-site VPN jump through 2 tunnels

Tags: vpn, nat, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I have 3 networks like on the below diagram:

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m3xT.png)

Subnet A: 10.0.1.0/24, public IP of VPN Gateway: 55.0.0.1
Subnet B: 172.30.0.0/24, public IP of VPN Gateway: 66.0.0.1
Subnet C: 172.20.0.0/24, public IP of VPN Gateway: 77.0.0.1

A and B are mine subnets, C is customer I don't have access to. On A and B I have configured Strongswan, and it's working as expected for traffic A<->B and B<->C. But I would like to pass traffic from A to C, without adding any new tunnels.

A setup:

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
conn A-to-B
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=55.0.0.1
    leftid=55.0.0.1
    leftsubnet=10.0.1.0/24
    right=66.0.0.1
    rightid=66.0.0.1
    rightsubnet=172.30.0.0/24
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=3des-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    rekey=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart
```

iptables on A:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Mon Jan 29 13:08:06 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [40025608:40188078680]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30069133:18566093721]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [30069133:18566093721]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan 29 13:08:06 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Mon Jan 29 13:08:06 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [39774:2679080]
:INPUT ACCEPT [8831:584395]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1423:122095]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [32360:2215502]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.0.0/24 -o ens10 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.30.0.0/24 -o ens10 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o ens10 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o ens10 -j MASQUERADE
```

B setup:

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
conn B-to-A
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=66.0.0.1
    leftid=66.0.0.1
    leftsubnet=172.30.0.0/24
    right=55.0.0.1
    rightid=55.0.0.1
    rightsubnet=10.0.1.0/24
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=3des-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    rekey=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart
conn B-to-C
    type=tunnel
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    left=66.0.0.1
    leftid=66.0.0.1
    leftsubnet=172.30.0.0/24
    right=77.0.0.1
    rightid=77.0.0.1
    rightsubnet=172.20.0.0/24
    ike=3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=3des-sha1!
    aggressive=no
    keyingtries=%forever
    ikelifetime=28800s
    lifetime=3600s
    dpddelay=30s
    dpdtimeout=120s
    dpdaction=restart
```

B iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Mon Jan 29 13:11:52 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [41835373:31455924194]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [65626379:68193057513]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [49075459:43200854736]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -s 172.30.0.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -i ens10 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.1.0/24 -d 172.30.0.0/24 -i eth0 -o ens10 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 172.30.0.0/24 -d 172.20.0.0/24 -i ens10 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 172.20.0.0/24 -d 172.30.0.0/24 -i eth0 -o ens10 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan 29 13:11:52 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Mon Jan 29 13:11:52 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [139914:9106692]
:INPUT ACCEPT [52056:3907832]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5562:617847]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [76991:4903875]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o ens10 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o ens10 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o ens10 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o ens10 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan 29 13:11:52 2024
```

With tcpdump from A to C (and configuring routing on A to C through B), I was able to see packets coming in, but in addition there was some public IP address. It's not happening with traceroute from B to C directly:

```
13:16:01.978860 IP 10.0.1.111.40062 > 172.20.0.12.445: Flags [S], seq 645287854, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3079411417 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:16:01.978959 IP 116.203.82.31.40062 > 172.20.0.12.445: Flags [S], seq 645287854, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3079411417 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Do you see any obvious issue I have in this setup? Typically I configured only direct s2s VPNs, so I'm not sure if this is all I need to configure.